# Thenable функция. При вызове фуникции один тип при применении `then` или `await` другой тип

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-типы, типизация

В js простой пример

```
function thenable() {
    return 'just function'
}
thenable.then = (resolve) => {
    resolve('like a Promise')
}
(async function main() {
    //behave like a function
    const functionResult = thenable()
    //behave like a Promise
    const promiseLikeResult = await thenable
    console.log(functionResult);
    console.log(promiseLikeResult);


})()
```

Возможно ли протипизировать это с помощью typescript, когда мы вызываем функцию возвращаемый тип `string[]`(['just function']) когда делаем `await` возвращаемый тип  `string` ('like a Promise')?

Comment: _Type of 'await' operand must either be a valid promise or must not contain a callable 'then' member._

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно :)